# How to make values of a column comma-separated?

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have an input file with single value columns as below:

**Input file:**

```
B00000|1|def|b12  
B00001|1|xyz|
B00000|1||b11  
B00001|1|def|ab1  
B00001|2|ghi|bc2  
B00002|1|abc|ac1  
B00002|1|xyz|bc2
```

I need to delimit the data in third and fourth columns with respect to the first and second so as to get the output as:

**Output:**

```
B00000|1|def|b11,b12  
B00001|1|def,xyz|ab1  
B00001|2|ghi|bc2  
B00002|1|abc,xyz|ac1,bc2
```

Comment: Edited the question considering one more possibility of input data where 3rd or 4th column values could be empty. Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for bringing it to notice

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN          { OFS=FS="|"}

a[$1][$2][3]   { a[$1][$2][3] = a[$1][$2][3] "," $3;
                 a[$1][$2][4] = a[$1][$2][4] "," $4;
                 next }

               { a[$1][$2][3] = $3;
                 a[$1][$2][4] = $4   }

END            { for (b in a)
                    for(c in a[b]) print b,c,a[b][c][3],a[b][c][4] }
```

Please see @dave_thompson_085' comment bellow about a correspondent version for awk (using one-dimensional arrays)

Comment: array-of-array is gawk-only, but you could do two parallel (1D) arrays each keyed by the concatentation `$1"|"$2` (or prettier `$1 FS $2`) in any awk. Also, your existence test would malfunction if the first-encountered `$3` value(s) for a `$1,$2` pair is (each) empty or a representation of zero, although the example data does not suggest that happens; with the 1D method `$1"|"$2 in ary3` works for any field values. Finally, if the output should be sorted, in recent gawk (v4) only you can use `PROC_INFO["SORTED_IN"]` to control the `for`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thank you!!  I dont know why but my gawk  4.1.3 by default is sorting the `for in`.

Comment: @JJoao can you please update the answer with 1D method. Its not possible for me to run gawk.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
B00000|1|def|b12  
B00001|1|xyz|a11  
B00000|1|abc|b11  
B00001|1|def|ab1  
B00001|2|ghi|bc2  
B00002|1|abc|ac1  
B00002|1|xyz|bc2  

$ perl -ne '($k,$v1,$v2)=/([^|]+\|[^|]+\|)([^|]+)\|([^ ]*)/;
$h1{$k}.=$h1{$k}?",$v1":$v1; $h2{$k}.=$h2{$k}?",$v2":$v2;
END{ foreach (keys %h1){print "$_$h1{$_}|$h2{$_}\n"} }
' ip.txt 
B00001|2|ghi|bc2
B00002|1|abc,xyz|ac1,bc2
B00000|1|def,abc|b12,b11
B00001|1|xyz,def|a11,ab1
```

- The input line is split into three parts, for ex: `B00000|1|` , `def` and `b12`. Trailing whitespace in line is ignored
- In two different hash variables, having same key, the values `$v1` and `$v2` are appended. `,` is added if hash value for the key is non-empty
- After all lines are processed, output is printed

If input and keys are sorted:

```
$ sort ip.txt | perl -ne '($k,$v1,$v2)=/([^|]+\|[^|]+\|)([^|]+)\|([^ ]*)/;
$h1{$k}.=$h1{$k}?",$v1":$v1; $h2{$k}.=$h2{$k}?",$v2":$v2;
END{ foreach (sort keys %h1){print "$_$h1{$_}|$h2{$_}\n"} }'
B00000|1|abc,def|b11,b12
B00001|1|def,xyz|ab1,a11
B00001|2|ghi|bc2
B00002|1|abc,xyz|ac1,bc2
```